# Redrawing A Simple Graph

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, line, d3.js

I have a pretty simple line graph that is rendered by the code below. I have created a simple timer to push items into the data array and then redraw the graph. The problem is that the graph is not being redrawn. I can see that the line function is called every 1.5 seconds as expected, but the graph is just not redrawing.

I have tried a number of different things, and have tried to follow some of the answers to previous questions similar to this on SO, but I'm just stuck.

```
    var data = getData();
    var graph;
    var line;

    function getData() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
            arr.push(rand(100));
        }
        return arr;
    }

    function rand(max) {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1))
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        data.shift();
        data.push(rand(100));
        redraw();
    }, 1500);

    function redraw() {
        graph.select("svg path")
             .data([data])
             .attr("d", line);
    }

    var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
    var w = 1000 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
    var h = 400 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([h, 0]);

    line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
             .y(function(d) { return y(d); })

    graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
              .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
              .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
              .append("svg:g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
    graph.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
          .call(xAxis);


    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");
    graph.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
          .call(yAxisLeft);

    graph.append("svg:path")
         .data([data])         
         .attr("d", line);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your selector "svg path" isn’t specific enough: it matches the domain path drawn by your axes. You can fix that in one of two ways. You can either save a reference to the line path when you add it:

```
var path = graph.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("d", line);
```

Or you could assign it a specific class ("line") and then use a more specific selector (".line"). This will make it easier to style, as well.

```
graph.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```